# django csrf token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, html, django, forms, csrf

I keep getting this error when submitting a POST request with a form:

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

and then it says that the CSRF token missing or incorrect. I definitely included the token in my html, and here's my views method:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/texts')
    else:
        form = TextForm()   
    return render_to_response('texts/index.html', {'form': form}, 
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What am I doing wrong?? I've tried a bunch of different things but nothing is fixing it.

Here's the index.html:

```
<h1> Texts </h1>
<form action="/texts/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<hr>
```

Comment: can you show how you include `csrf_token` in your html?

Comment: give your `index.html` .

Comment: Have you included 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your list of middleware classes in your settings.

Comment: yes I have that included

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf

Comment: I read through the doc, but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I add @csrf_exempt to the view, then it works, but otherwise it doesn't.